# What do these items on a Jeppesen VOR approach chart mean?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, iaps, jeppesen, minimums

I have some questions about certain VOR approach charts. I find some details confusing on the following chart for SLTJ VOR C Rwy 13:

1. What does "state" mean? It's in bold in the minima section.
2. Why is there a bold "1" next to the minima?
3. Referring to a non-precision VOR approach chart, why is the minima stated as 1DA/MDA 6950'? Shouldn't it be just MDA? The number "1" is also next to it.
4. Above the minima, what do the initials CDFA stand for?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. The "State" label refers to the source of the values in the minimums box, in this case meaning they are from the respective state authority:

   > A "Std" label in the upper left corner of the minimums box indicates that the published visibilities are ICAO
   > Doc 9365 compliant. Other labels, as described below, indicate compliance with other regulations.
   >
   > [...]
   >
   > **Std/State** - Minimums are based on tables and rules from a State
   > Regulation which is similar/close to ICAO Doc 9365 (e.g. EASA AIR OPS,
   > Indian CAR), refer also to AIR TRAFFIC CONTROL - Aerodrome
   > Operating Minimums JEPPESEN for identified differences to ICAO
   > Doc 9365. No comparison has been done to any other landing minimums
   > criteria.

   <sup>([Jeppesen Approach Chart Legend Minimums](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Approach_Chart_Legend_Minimums.pdf))</sup>
2. That is a footnote. You can find the note further below on the chart:

   [image: SLTJ VOR C Rwy 13 Minima]

   It means that using DA instead of MDA depends on your airline operating procedures.
3. Usually a non-precision approach uses an MDA (minimum descent altitude). But when flying a CDFA approach (see 4.), this may be replaced by a DA (decision altitude). Your airline operating procedure will stipulate how much safety margin to add to the given minima values when using them as a DA.
4. CDFA stands for [Continuous Descent Final Approach](https://skybrary.aero/articles/continuous-descent-final-approach-cdfa). It means that you will not level off at MDA. Instead you start your final descent later in order to descend continuously towards the runway.